# Checking membership in a sequence preferred style

Tags: python

What is the most pythonic way to do the following.

```
if x in range(4):
....
if x in [0, 1, 2, 3]:
....
if x in (0, 1, 2, 3):
....
```

Although they are all a similar result, what is more python?

Comment: `0 <= x <= 3`, or just use a set (rather than tuple or list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my mind, hard coding the values from one to three is not a good idea. What if you had to check whether a number was in range `[0; 1000000)`? In that case `range` (or `xrange` in Python 2.7) would be better.

What's more, lists and tuples actually consume memory, while `range` in Python 3.x can *compute* whether a number is in `range` or not, which makes it fast and lightweight.

Comment: `range` in Python 3.x will be O(1) -  `xrange` in Python 2.7 will still be O(N) as it has to do a sequential scan... `if lower <= n < upper` is readable enough and doesn't rely on implementation differences between versions.

Comment: @JonClements , thanks, corrected that.